# SimpleImputer ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm trying to replace NaNs with mean values, but when i do the fit method I get this error:

> ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for
> dtype('float64').

This is my code:

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values = "NaN", strategy = "mean")
imp = imp.fit(df_missing.iloc[:, 1:4])
```

Before you flag it as repost, I know I might import numpy as well and use np.nan instead of "NaN", but isn't there a way to work around it and stick to pandas and SimpleImputer? I was following an online course and I'd like to stick to it as much as I can; unfortunately it's apparently outdated and, for example, it still runs

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
```

Comment: `df.fillna(df.mean())`?

Comment: The porpose was actually to get familiar with sklearn, I know I can do it with pandas or numpy but I was wondering if I also might do it with SimpleImputer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question clearly or not, but I assume instead of `pd.NA or np.nan` in the columns you want to impute, you have `"NaN"`(an object type). If that's the case, there's a way to work around it:

```
df_missing.iloc[:, 1:4] = df_missing.iloc[:, 1:4].replace({"NaN": np.nan})
```

By doing so, first you replace `"NaN"` with `np.nan`, and then you can use SimpleImputer:

```
imp = SimpleImputer(strategy = "mean")
imp = imp.fit(df_missing.iloc[:, 1:4])
```

I hope I understood your question right, and this solution helps you!

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I was trying to avoid using numpy at all. The online course I'm studying might still use some deprecated functions and libraries so I'm not sure it can be done

Answer (score -1):

You can set imp object;

`imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values = np.nan, strategy = "mean")`

Comment: OP has already stated "*I know I might import numpy as well and use np.nan instead of "NaN", but [...]*"